# Android NDK error No such file or directory for a path that exists in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, native

I get the following error in Eclipse:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project com.opera.sdk.Opera ****

D:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++ thumb : operanative <= main.cpp

In file included from jni/src/main.cpp:4:0:
jni/include/controller.hpp:6:28: fatal error: gogi_opera_api.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/operanative/src/main.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

This is my Android.mk makefile:

```
MY_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libopera
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libopera.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# final library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE     := operanative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := src/main.cpp \
                    src/controller.cpp \
                    src/lock.cpp \
                    src/event.cpp \
                    src/dialog.cpp \
                    src/queue.cpp \
                    src/screen.cpp \
                    src/surface.cpp \
                    src/timer.cpp \
                    src/waiter.cpp \
                    src/window.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni/include \
                    $(GOGI_SDK_PATH)/include \
                    $(GOGI_SDK_PATH)/jsplugins/ooif/include
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libopera
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is my Application.mk file:

```
APP_STL:=stlport_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

And the controller.hpp file in questiuon has these defines:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_HPP
#define CONTROLLER_HPP

#include <memory>

#include "gogi_opera_api.h"

#include "event.hpp"
#include "dialog.hpp"
#include "queue.hpp"
#include "screen.hpp"
#include "surface.hpp"
#include "timer.hpp"
#include "waiter.hpp"
#include "window.hpp"
```

I have the files in their proper locations and I've rewritten the application.mk as required, and yet I get the above build error.

Comment: GOGI_SDK_PATH is not defined in Android.mk. So it comes from the environment, or maybe from the command line. Verify that this path is defined correctly. Run ndk-build with **V=1** on command line. You will see the parameters that are actually passed to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

change *.hpp to *.cpp

It was working for me in echoprint project.